# How does flutter convert a hex string to a binary string?

Tags: dart, binary, flutter, hex

Is there a direct conversion method? I need to convert AA to 1010 1010

Comment: Could you give more context into why you need this?

Comment: I am working on an IoT device, the hardware will send two hexadecimal numbers like AA, I need to convert to binary, because binary (1010 1010) represents some status information.

Comment: Are you sure `AA` isn't already binary? `AA` and `1010 1010` might only be 2 different ways to display the binary value. My answer below is only relevant if you get `AA` as string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the radix for `int.parse` and `toRadixString`

```
print(int.parse('AA',radix: 16).toRadixString(2));
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer was a BIG help for me.  I added .padLeft(4, "0") in case the binary number is less than 4 digits.  Like this:  int.parse("0", radix: 16).toRadixString(2).padLeft(4, "0")

Comment: @masaya Thanks, glad to hear 